# Why was Naaman afflicted with tzaraas specifically?

Tags: gentiles, reward-punishment, melachim-kings-book-of, tzaraas-negaim

In [Kings II 5:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15911#showrashi=true&v=1) we are told that Naaman the general of Aram was afflicted with tzaraas. I have seen several explanations which outline something he did wrong, the punishment for which was tzaraas. However, from what I understand tzaraas is a spiritual affliction, which seems to have very little to do with non-Jews ([see Negaim](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h63.htm) chapters 3, 11, and 12 the first mishna in each). In every answer I have seen we could replace tzaraas with any other disease and the 'effect' (ie the spiritual tit-for-tat punishment to Naaman) would have been the same.

I would like to know if there is a reason that Naaman was punished with this disease specifically.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16663/759

Answer (score 4):

The [Midrash (Bamidbar Rabbah 7:5)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba4/7.htm) lists 11 causes for Tzaraat and brings proof for each one of them.

On of the causes listed is Haughtiness, and Naaman is used as a proof. The verse says, "וְנַעֲמָן שַׂר צְבָא מֶלֶךְ אֲרָם הָיָה אִישׁ גָּדוֹל", and the Midrash defines "Gadol" as being haughty, since he was a great warrior.

[This article](http://www.torah.org/learning/haftorah/tazria.html) says that Naaman's feelings of greatness were undeserved, since he unwittingly killed Achav (see Rashi on [Melachim I 22:34](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15906#showrashi=true&v=34)), and his punishment was tzaraat.

Text of the Midrash:

> ועל גסות הרוח, זה נעמן, שנאמר (מלכים ב ה):(ונעמן): [שר צבא מלך ארם] היה איש גדול. 
>   מהו גדול? 
>   שהיתה רוחו גסה, מפני שהיה גבור חיל, ועל ידי כך נצטרע.

Comment: See however a different version of the Midrash on [Arachin 16a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=16&format=pdf).

Comment: @doubleaa. While different it is not contradictory. It just brings a different proof that haughtiness bring tzaraat.

Comment: But It also gives a different reason for Naaman's tzaraat.

Comment: @DoubleAA: The reference to Naaman is in regards to Gechazi. He lied to Elisha and told him he didn't do anything, when in reality he went to collect payment from Naaman.

Comment: non-Jews are punished for haughtiness? Why this person specifically as opposed to say Pharaoh or Hiram who claimed to be gods themselves.

Comment: @pleaseremovemyaccount: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Menachem [awesome, thanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm)

Comment: @pleaseremovemyaccount: you're asking a separate question. Something along the lines of "why were some non-jews punished in specific ways and not others?", or something like that. You should ask it as a question and see what kind of answers you get.